# How to forward SMB using Ngrok？

Tags: smb, ngrok

I learned about SMB infomation from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Message_Block.

SMB use tcp 139/445 prot. And I check my server prot by `lsof`,SMB only listen 139 and 445 prot.

Then I try forward SMB port by Ngrok. This is my config:

```
tunnels:
  http:
    remote_port: 1122
    proto:
      tcp: 5000
  smb:
    remote_port: 139
    proto:
      tcp: 139
  smb2:
    remote_port: 445
    proto:
      tcp: 445
```

The http server is work. But SMB server not work.

Ngrok clone from https://github.com/inconshreveable/ngrok. Version is 1.7 and build by golang 1.12

Answer (score 0):

Try with this syntax:

```
  smb:
    addr: 139
    proto: tcp
  smb2:
    addr: 445
    proto: tcp
```

You can read about ngrok syntax for tunnels in [ngrok documentation tunnel definition](https://ngrok.com/docs/agent/config/#tunnel-configurations).

Comment: @Markus Why do you change link from specific doc to`proto:` to the general one? I think I'm missing something.